# Problema con WHERE con variables

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver desde hace varios días. 
Tengo que usar una variable llamada `$swhere` en donde tengo condicionales para una búsqueda. Eso funciona perfecto.

```
$sWhere = "";
        if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }
```

El problema es que necesito pasar otras condiciones *sql*.

```
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuál es tu problema... no corre? manda algún error? devuelve datos incorrectos?

Comment: Una vez que declareste la variable al principio: `$sWhere = "";` en todas las otras partes debes concatenar con `.=`, de lo contrario, te sustituirá todo con un nuevo contenido incompleto. Algo así: `if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
            }
            $sWhere .= substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }`

Comment: De todos modos es absurdo perder el tiempo haciendo que esto funcione. Tu variable `$q` representa un serio problema de seguridad y deberías usar consultas preparadas para esto. Afrontar situaciones como estas es más simple y más seguro de ese modo, porque se usan marcadores y puedes con suma facilidad crear consultas con criterios dinámicos, pero ese es ya otro tema.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un array para almacenar los filtros:

```
    $sWhere = '';
    $where = [];
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        // Otro array para tener solo búsqueda que contiene el texto
        $like = [];
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $like[] = "{$aColumns[$i]} LIKE '%$q%'";
        }
        // Al final los unes con implode y encierras entre paréntesis
        // Guardando en $where, que es el que va a crear el filtro
        $where[] = '(' . implode(' OR ', $like) . ')';
    }
    // Si es necesario agregar más campos:
    if(isset($_GET['otro_campo']) && $_GET['otro_campo'] != '') {
        $otro = $_GET['otro_campo'];
        $where[] = "otra_columna = '$otro'";
    }
    // Al final creas el where solo si es necesario
    if(count($where) > 0) {
        $sWhere = ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    }
```

Finalmente, es muy mala idea colocar los datos introducidos por un usuario en consulta a base de datos sin haber revisado y saneado previamente, porque hay riesgo de inyección de comandos, creando un gran daño.

Lo recomendable es que uses consultas preparadas.

Comment: Yo empezaría por el clásico `where true ` y luego a medida que vas comprobando los parámetros vas concatenando cada nueva condición con `and ( tu_condicion) `