# Múltiple búsqueda SQL desde formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Tengo un registro en MySQL de registros a través de un formulario, y ahora necesito hacer un buscador que, dependiendo del número de campos del formulario rellenos, haga una consulta u otra.
Sé que, con unos cuantos if/else podría hacer la búsqueda, pero con tantas líneas de código creo que tiene que haber una forma más eficiente. Algo que identifique qué partes del formulario se han rellenado y cree una sentencia SQL dependiendo de eso. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el formulario y cómo estás armando la consulta. Creo que algo como [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336849/problema-con-where-con-variables/336974#336974) podría servirte.

Comment: El formulario es demasiado extenso (440 líneas), el array que imprime $_POST es Array ( [alta_baja] => [entrada_salida] => [usuario] => [fecha] => [referencia_documento] => [tipo] => [fecha_documento] => [para_de] => [asunto] => [inputTipoDeDocumento] => [notificacion_interna] => [numero_terceros] => [nif_cif] => [nombre_tercero] => [telefono_movil] => [telefono_fijo] => [email] => [centro_coste] => [descripcion] => [submit] => ). Necesito que, si alguno de los campos tiene un valor asociado, haga la consulta con esos valores

Comment: Igualmente, el enlace que refieres no me sirve de mucho, el array ya lo saca sin problemas y las claves de cada posición corresponden a las columnas de la BD

Comment: Generalmente no se suelen usar todos los criterios para una consulta, sino sólo algunos, como ID, Nombre etc. La mejor forma de resolver esto sería agrupando en el formulario los campos que sirven como criterios de búsqueda, esos datos los puedes serializar aparte y luego en PHP construir el criterio de búsqueda. Es relativamente fácil hacerlo implementando Ajax desde el cliente, enviarías a PHP un objeto así más o menos: `{ buscar: {nombre:"Pedro", apellido: "Cobos"}, otrosDatos: {dato1: "d1", dato2: "d2"} }` ahí tienes dos grupos de datos, siendo `buscar` el que agrupa los criterios.

Comment: En este caso, si que tengo que buscar por todos los datos, como ya he dicho. O bien por uno de ellos, o bien por varios (incluso podría ser por todos), por lo que es indiferente buscar por Ajax o por una consulta desde php